# Prove that the area centroid of a planar region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ projects onto that of its projection onto the $xy$-plane

Tags: calculus, integration, computational-geometry, projection, centroid

Consider an arbitrary convex bounded region $\Omega'\in\mathbb{R}^2$ which is the projection onto the $xy$-plane of a region $\Omega$ that lies on a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (that is not parallel to the $xy$-plane). Can someone help me prove that the area centroid* of $\Omega'$ is equal to the projection of the area centroid of $\Omega$ onto the $xy$-plane? Does the same hold for non-convex regions too?

*The employed definition of the area centroid $(x_c, y_c)$ of some region $\mathcal{R}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is
$$ x_c = \frac{1}{A_{\mathcal{R}}}\!\!\iint_{\mathcal{R}}x\ dxdy,\quad y_c = \frac{1}{A_{\mathcal{R}}}\!\!\iint_{\mathcal{R}}y\ dxdy, $$
where $A_{\mathcal{R}}$ is the area of $\mathcal{R}$.

$\bf{Edit: }$ What I'm currently appealing to is that the 'shape' of $\Omega$ can be obtained by linearly scaling $\Omega'$ by some factor $c$ in the direction orthogonal to the intersection of the $xy$-plane and the plane containing $\Omega$. Therefore, since the area scales linearly as well, this gives

$$ x_{c,\Omega} = \frac{1}{cA_{\Omega'}}\!\!\iint_{\Omega'}x\ (c\ dxdy) = \frac{1}{A_{\Omega'}}\!\!\iint_{\Omega'}x\ dxdy,$$
and likewise for $y_{c,\Omega}$.

Comment: What’s your definition of area centroid? You need some notion of weight or density otherwise this is false.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for pointing this out. I have clarified this in the post

Comment: Well, the projection of an (x,y,z) point  on the xy-plane is just (x,y). The z coordinate vanishes and the xy coordinates stay the same for each point and its projection. If you keep that in mind you should have no trouble finding a proof. Whether you find the centroid in R3 or R2 you'll have the same xc,yc since the x and y in the integrals are the same. You just have the extra zc in R3 which vanishes when projecting.

Comment: @JohnKatsantas Okay, I see what you're saying. But my conflict arises from not being able to find equations defining the area centroid of a planar region in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So given the above definition for the area centroid of a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$, would it not be necessary to have a local $\xi\eta$-coordinate system to compute the area centroid of $\Omega$? Therefore, when projecting onto $\Omega'$, wouldn't the coordinate system transformation need to be taken into account as well?

Comment: @niran90 If I'm not mistaken, the centroid in 3D is defined by $x_c=\frac{\iiint_Vxdxdydz}{V}$ where V is the volume between a curve and the xy plane (the curve happens to be a plane in your case ). The other centroid coordinates are defined similarly.  So, if you go a step further and eliminate dZ , it should cancel a part of V in the denominator and end up being equal to the $x_c$ you defined in your question.

Comment: @niran90 That aside, I don't specialize in mathematics and I'm not to be trusted when it comes to proofs. Hopefully, I gave you some ideas until someone gives you a proper and detailed answer.

Comment: @JohnKatsantas Thanks for the insights! I think you're right about appealing to the definition of the volume centroid of the volume bounded between $\Omega$ and the $xy$-plane.

Comment: @niran90 After thinking about this a bit more, I think the centroid of the volume is different and doesn't match with the other centroids we've mentioned. Nevertheless, I wrote an answer. I think it's pretty close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nobody has answered so I'll give it a shot. I'll probably assume something I'm not allowed to in the process so if anyone catches anything let me know so I can adjust it. Anyway, I will only refer to the 'x' coordinate but the same applies for 'y'.

If the region consisted of discrete points, I think we can agree that the x coordinate of the centroid would be given by $x_c=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{i=N}x_i}{N}$ where N is the number of points. Extending that to infinite points, we can define the centroid of the region in $R^3$ as $$x_c=\frac{\iint_SxdS}{S}$$ where $S$ is the surface area of the region in $R^3$. So, we integrate $x$ over the surface of the region. If you  agree with this definition of the centroid, we can prove what you asked as shown below. Given that the region is in the form of $z=f(x,y)$ we can write (you can look it up if you don't know this):
$$dS=\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}\times dA$$

Note that the $A$ that showed up is the area of the projection of the region.Knowing this, the rest is simple. Let's set$\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}=K$

1.$$S=\iint_S{dS}=\iint_A Kdxdy$$

2.$$x_c=\frac{\iint_SxdS}{S}=\frac{\iint_AxKdxdy}{\iint_A Kdxdy}=\frac{\iint_Axdxdy}{\iint_A dxdy}$$

Now, I repeat that this $A$ we ended up with is the area of the projection and since ${\iint_A dxdy}=A$ then :
$$x_c=\frac{1}{A}\iint_Axdxdy$$

which is also the centroid of the 2d projection.

Regarding the *non-convex part of the question*, it seems that a non-convex shape doesn't change the proof. Unless there is something in the proof we shouldn't do if the region is non-convex (or my proof is wrong - which is not impossible), then the same should hold for the centroid of a non-convex region.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This really clarified things for me. I had previously intuited (see the 'Edit' section of my post) that $\Omega$ must be some linear scaling of $\Omega'$, but that just didn't feel rigorous enough for me. Thanks again!